# Where is the core dump file written for a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, dump

I am starting a Spring Boot application in Windows using `winsw` and after it crashes I can't find the Java core dump file anywhere.

Where will the Java core dump file be located?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of where Java core dumps are located on Windows gets a little complicated. The commonest answers are:

- `$JAVA_HOME/bin`
- The current working directory of the process

The file is typically named `hs_err_<PID>`.

However, rather than guessing you can **tell** Java where to write a dump file.

The default JVM argument for this, in Oracle JVMs, is: `-XX:HeapDumpPath`. For example:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/dumps/directory/java_pid<pid>.hprof`
```

IBM provides its own flavour: `-Xdump`. For example

```
-Xdump:heap:label=/path/to/dumps/directory/heapdump.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.dump
-Xdump:java:label=/path/to/dumps/directory/core.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.dump
```

And if you run with `-Xdump:what` then a log event will be written to STDOUT on startup showing your the various dump parameters you have chosen.

Comment: Isn't `-Xdump:` an IBM-specific VM option?